# OCaml error on class definition

Tags: ocaml

I am defining a class as follows

```
    class dataframe (csv_filepath:string) =
        object
               (* Load the csv, make it square and print the first line *)
               initializer  
                    let print_first_line csv_filepath =
                        let f = Csv.square (Csv.load csv_filepath) in
                        let top_line = Csv.sub 0 0 1 (Csv.columns f) f in
                        Csv.print_readable top_line;
                        Printf.printf "\n";
        end;;
```

and receiving the error message

```
   end;;
   ^^^
   Error: Syntax error
```

I do not see anything wrong with this, I am totally lost, anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write an expression at the initializer. What you write here is a function definition toplevel phrase. The proper initializer should look like::

```
initializer
  let print_first_line csv_filepath =
    let f = Csv.square (Csv.load csv_filepath) in
    let top_line = Csv.sub 0 0 1 (Csv.columns f) f in
    Csv.print_readable top_line;
    Printf.printf "\n"
  in
  (* Use print_first_line you defined *)
  print_first_line csv_filepath
```

or just simply

```
initializer
  let f = Csv.square (Csv.load csv_filepath) in
  let top_line = Csv.sub 0 0 1 (Csv.columns f) f in
  Csv.print_readable top_line;
  Printf.printf "\n"
```